# toggle button on click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First, let me clear you all one thing that i have already searched a lot but couldn't find the answer which will solve my problem. I have a button which when i click it's icon changes and some functions called than when i again click on that button it's icon must be revert and same functions called again.

I have this button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" id="voice_icon" title="microphone">
<i style="font-size: 24px;" class="fa fa-microphone fa-2x voice_control" id="voice_control"></i>
<small class="toolbar-label mic-btn" id="mic">Mic.</small>
</button>
```

while clicking on that button these functions and classes should be called:

```
$('#voice_icon').click(function () {
        voiceAtion.voice();
        test.start();
        $('#voice_control').addClass("fa-microphone-slash").removeClass("fa-microphone");
        $('#mic').html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-1x fa-fw'></i>");
    });
```

And when i again click on that icon these icons and classes should be called again :

```
test.abort();
$('#voice_control').addClass("fa-microphone").removeClass("fa-microphone-slash");
$('#mic').html("Mic.");
```

```js
$('#voice_icon').click(function() {
  voiceAtion.voice();
  test.start();
  $('#voice_control').addClass("fa-microphone-slash").removeClass("fa-microphone");
  $('#mic').html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-1x fa-fw'></i>");
});

test.abort();
$('#voice_control').addClass("fa-microphone").removeClass("fa-microphone-slash");
$('#mic').html("Mic.");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="voice_icon" title="microphone">
<i style="font-size: 24px;" class="fa fa-microphone fa-2x voice_control" id="voice_control"></i>
<small class="toolbar-label mic-btn" id="mic">Mic.</small>
</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this first time click goes to else and for second click it goes to if. so on..

```js
$('#voice_icon').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
    //first code
  } else {
     //second code
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

Comment: It's not working in the first time but working fine when i again clicks the button

Comment: It will works .. in first click it goes to else condition. check fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/p28ppsjb/

Comment: Initially `var clicks` takes `undefined` value so it will goes to `else` or you can swap your first and second code

Comment: what's the meaning of $(this).data("clicks", !clicks); this line?

Comment: In your case `$(this).data("clicks", !clicks);` `!clicks` which is opposite value stores in to the `clicks` so every time you get only `true` and `false` which is exactly you required in this case

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `addClass/removeClass` use `toggleClass`.

```
$('#voice_control').toggleClass("fa-microphone-slash fa-microphone");
```

Comment: Only partial correct, You missed `test.abort();` and `$('#mic').html("Mic.");`

Comment: @Satpal: if you think so, you can add your _complete_ solution, or write why this one should be just _partial_.

Comment: what about the functions?

Answer (score 0):

use `hasClass` for check `which class to remove and add`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#voice_icon').click(function() {
    if ($('#voice_control').hasClass("fa-microphone")) {

      $('#voice_control').addClass("fa-microphone-slash").removeClass("fa-microphone");
      $('#mic').html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-1x fa-fw'></i>");
    } else {
      $('#voice_control').addClass("fa-microphone").removeClass("fa-microphone-slash");
      $('#mic').html("Mic.");
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="voice_icon" title="microphone">
<i style="font-size: 24px;" class="fa fa-microphone fa-2x voice_control" id="voice_control"></i>
<small class="toolbar-label mic-btn" id="mic">Mic.</small>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   // You can also use global variable and check for true false:


   <button type="button" class="btn" id="voice_icon" title="microphone">
    <i style="font-size: 24px;" class="fa fa-microphone fa-2x voice_control" id="voice_control"></i>
    <small class="toolbar-label mic-btn" id="mic">Mic.</small>
</button>

    <script>
        var x = true;
        $('#voice_icon').click(function () {
            if(x){
               $('#voice_control').removeClass("fa-microphone").addClass("fa-microphone-slash")
               x = false;
           }
           else{
               $('#voice_control').addClass("fa-microphone").removeClass("fa-microphone-slash")
               x = true;
           }
            $('#mic').html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-1x fa-fw'></i>");
        });
    </script>
```